# Where to add role based authentication to MeanJS app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, roles, meanjs

I have a meanjs starter template (with yeoman generator). 
Where can I add specific permissions to my modules? For instance,

```
'use strict';

// Configuring the Articles module
angular.module('adminpanel').run(['Menus',
    function(Menus) {
        // Set top bar menu items
        //Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', 'admin panel', 'adminpanel/', 'adminpanel');

        Menus.addMenuItem('topbar', 'Admin Panel', 'adminpanel', 'dropdown', '/buildings(/create)?');
        Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'adminpanel', 'List Collections', 'adminpanel/collections');
    }
]);
```

and the routes like so
   'use strict';

```
//Setting up route
angular.module('adminpanel').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        // Adminpanels state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('listCollections', {
            url: '/adminpanel/collections',
            templateUrl: 'modules/adminpanels/views/list-collections.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('showCollection', {
            url: '/adminpanel/collections/:collectionName',
            templateUrl: 'modules/adminpanels/views/show-collection.client.view.html'
        }).
        state('showCollectionItem', {
            url: '/adminpanel/collections/:collectionName/:itemId',
            templateUrl: 'modules/adminpanels/views/show-item.client.view.html'
        });
    }
]);
```

Are these the correct places to add role-based authentication (on the client side), with added measure on the serverside (I've already done that)?

Does anybody know how I can add an option to the Menus.(some function), such as 'admin.hasPermission', without breaking it? Any resources on this sort of thing?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is right practice to put your authentication, authorization code at the client side as well as server side. They should be on the server side only.

The point is, you have to replicate your authentication and authorization code in the client, anyone can read your mechanism to handle these situation and once a loophole is discovered, it would simply be followed by your server code as well.

I believe authentication and authorization logic should be restricted to server side only. If I am up against someone professional, it would at least make his task tougher.

In case you insist, you can create a wrapper around `$http` service, maintain a key value pair of what role can do what, and ensure all AJAX request go through your wrapper service where you can check whether it should be allowed. If yes, you can simply forward the request using `$http` and if not, throw an error.

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated on the "security" on the clientside. For the client, the "security" I'm talking about is simply not rendering certain modules- e.g., in my topbar, the "Admin Panel" menu item should not be rendered unless the user is authenticated as an admin.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about any previous version, but with version 0.4.0 there are parameter in the client config to control the visibility:

If you set ***isPublic: false*** and add a ***roles*** array you can set the user that can see the menu entry:

```
    // Add the dropdown listCollentcions item
    Menus.addSubMenuItem('topbar', 'adminpanel', {
        title: 'listCollections',
        isPublic: false,
        roles:['admin'],
        state: 'adminpanel.listCollections'
    });
```

The implementation is in the core module (menu.client.services.js):

```
// A private function for rendering decision 
    var shouldRender = function(user) {
        if (user) {
            if (!!~this.roles.indexOf('*')) {
                return true;
            } else {
                for (var userRoleIndex in user.roles) {
                    for (var roleIndex in this.roles) {
                        if (this.roles[roleIndex] === user.roles[userRoleIndex]) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return this.isPublic;
        }

        return false;
    };
```

Maybe you can give version 0.4.0 a try or have a look at the code and try to implement it urself.